# mouseButton.y and mouseButton.x is -858993460 for every event except MouseButtonPressed

Tags: c++, sfml, events

Using SFML, every event type will produce a large negative value for x and y of -858993460.

```
if (menuEvent.type == sf::Event::GainedFocus 
    || menuEvent.type == sf::Event::LostFocus
    || menuEvent.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed 
    || menuEvent.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased 
    || menuEvent.type == sf::Event::MouseEntered
    || menuEvent.type == sf::Event::MouseMoved
    || menuEvent.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased
    || menuEvent.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed) {

    return HandleFindExit(menuEvent.mouseButton.x, menuEvent.mouseButton.y);
    // Except for when menuEvent.type is MouseButtonReleased 
    // or MouseButtonPressed x and y will be -858993460
}
```

I am wondering if this is an intended result or am I attempting to use these events incorrectly?

It seems to me there is a use case for knowing the position of the mouse cursor on MouseMoved, for example so you can have a button change to a different sprite as if you are hovering over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make sense that `mouseButton` won't have proper values except for events that involve the mouse button - MouseButtonReleased and MouseButtonPressed.

If for example you wanted the mouse position for MouseMoved events, you should be looking at the `mouseMove` member, which is of type `MouseMoveEvent`.

[Always use the right event data for the event type](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-events.php). A mapping can be found in [source code](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/Event_8hpp_source.php):

```cpp
  221     union
  222     {
  223         SizeEvent             size;              
  224         KeyEvent              key;               
  225         TextEvent             text;              
  226         MouseMoveEvent        mouseMove;         
  227         MouseButtonEvent      mouseButton;       
  228         MouseWheelEvent       mouseWheel;        
  229         MouseWheelScrollEvent mouseWheelScroll;  
  230         JoystickMoveEvent     joystickMove;      
  231         JoystickButtonEvent   joystickButton;    
  232         JoystickConnectEvent  joystickConnect;   
  233         TouchEvent            touch;             
  234         SensorEvent           sensor;            
  235     };
```

FYI -858993460 in hexadecimal is CCCCCCCC. It is a garbage value used by microsoft compilers for uninitialised values.

Comment: Yep, on any MouseEntered, MouseMoved, MouseButtonReleased, MouseButtonPressed events I can get the x and y from menuEvent.mouseMove.x or y. Thanks.